# Calling functions with arguments on "command" and "bind"

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to point, that i am learning python since short time. 
The question is going be to beginner one.

I need to add command to menu at top of program, which would call function "color_picker("red").

`kolory.add_command(label="Czerwony", command=color_picker('red'))` 
When i am using that, its somehow wrong, cuz its called once the program started, its not waiting for me to click the menu button. (i am sure of it, as i added "showinfo" to that function, and it shows the message before i do anything)
`kolory.add_command(label="Czerwony", command=lambda: color_picker('red'))` That one kinda works, but i don't know what does "lambda" mean here. Is it only way to call functions with arguments under menu options?

Same question goes to binding keyboard shortcuts.
`okno.bind("1", color_picker)` - that will call the function but does not have the argument, which should be a color. How can i do that?

So, how to assign functions WITH arguments, to keyboard shortcuts and to menu using add_command?

PS. Was searching trough google, but it seems python does not have so good documentation like c# does for example. Or i am too stupid to find it.

EDIT:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: color_picker() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thats the error message, when i try to use "pick_red" in okno.bind

Comment: Python documentation can be accessed via `help()` function in interactive python shell. In your case help `kolory.add_command` is probably the documentation you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but here goes;

The problem is that you are *calling* the `color_picker` function (by adding `()` after the function name).

What you want to do is pass the actual *function*, not the *result* of the function call as the `command` keyword argument, e.g. `add_command(label="Czerwony", command=color_picker)`

However, since you want to give it a fixed argument `'red'`, you must use [partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from `functools`, something like;

```
from functools import partial
pick_red = partial(color_picker, "red")
kolory.add_command(label="Czerwony", command=pick_red)
```

**EDIT**:

Now that your error message shows that you are using `Tkinter`, we can see that according to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) the function that is given to `bind()` is always passed an `event` parameter, so you need a function that can accept it;

```
def pick_red_with_event(event):
    # We really do nothing with event for now but we always get it...
    color_picker("red")

okno.bind("1", pick_red_with_event)
```

<strike>Same thing works for `okno.bind`, if you have defined `pick_red` as above, just do:</strike>

```
okno.bind("1", pick_red)
```

Comment: yes, you understood very well. Thats exactly what i meant. It works great with add_command, but it gives me an error with bind. I will post error message in my post.

Comment: re: "you must use partial from functools" - that statement is slightly incorrect. There's no reason you _must_ use it, but you certainly _can_ use it. You can also use lambda. This answer gives the impression that functools.partial is the only solution.